# Update Label On Another View

Tags: ios, swift, label, iboutlet

I have two views with a label on one of them. On the second view, there is a button. What I want to achieve here is to be able to press the button and it updates the label on the first view. How do I do that? I can't access the IBOutlet from the second view. Is there something that I have to do to the IBOutlet to make it public etc?

Comment: You mean 2 view controller or 2 view in a single view contorller ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use custom delegate method create a delegate in second view and access that view delegate function in first view. or use NSNotification or use NSUserdefaults

Answer (score 3):

You can use `NSNotificationCenter` for that.

First of all in your `viewDidLoad` method add this code in your `firstViewController` class:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "refreshlbl:", name: "refresh", object: nil)
```

which will `addObserver` when your app loads.

And add this helper method in same `viewController`.

```
func refreshlbl(notification: NSNotification) {

    lbl.text = "Updated by second View"  //Update your label here.
}
```

After that in your `secondViewController` add this code when you dismiss your view:

```
@IBAction func back(sender: AnyObject) {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("refresh", object: nil, userInfo: nil)
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

Now when you press back button from `secondView` then `refreshlbl` method will call from `firstView`.

Comment: Out of interest, I have two XIB files and am trying to achieve this. When clicking the button, I get the following error: "Unrecognized selector sent to instance". I have checked to ensure that the selector name is set to the same name as the function on the first view. Do you have any idea what the issue could be here, given that I am using two XIB files in my project instead of the main.storyboard?

Comment: Actually, I just fixed it by adding a colon at the end of the selector name! I've up voted your comment!